# Unit Testing ViewModel

Tags: android, unit-testing, mvvm, kotlin, viewmodel

I'm trying to use MVVM design pattern and try to do some Unit Test on a View Model. In the View Model the repository implementation is injected. What I'm trying to do is to test the View Model with a mocked repository. This is my code:

**IntroViewModel**

```
class IntroViewModel : ViewModel() {

   @Inject
   lateinit var userRepository: UserRepositoryImpl

   init {
      App.appComponent.inject(this)
   }

   var loggedIn: MutableLiveData<Boolean> = MutableLiveData()

   fun checkLoginStatus() {
      loggedIn.postValue(userRepository.isUserLoggedIn())
   }
}
```

**UserRepositoryImpl**

```
class UserRepositoryImpl: UserRepository {
    override fun isUserLoggedIn(): Boolean {
        return FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!=null
    }
}
```

**IntroTest**

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
@SmallTest
class IntroTest {

    @get:Rule
    val rule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    lateinit var introViewModel: IntroViewModel

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        introViewModel = IntroViewModel()
    }

    @Test
    fun checkFirebaseState_test() {

        val shouldReturn = true

        introViewModel.checkLoginStatus()

        assertEquals(shouldReturn, introViewModel.loggedIn.value)

    }
}
```

I want at the moment of the test to use another UserRepository implementation so that the test will not rely on FirebaseAuth or other source of information.

Comment: Actually I found out what was the issue. The var userRepository: UserRepositoryImpl should be of type UserRepository.